# Windows XP/Vista/7 application that targets external monitor

Tags: windows, external, multiple-monitors

I'm thinking to create a simple game that displays itself on the external monitor, if it's available.

I would be pleased to have this as simple as possible, in other words the programming handles the activation of the external monitor, and targets the gamewindow there automatically on start (by a commandline tool, api, ?). A mirror view would do fine as well.

Is this even possible? Would there be a good alternative, besides having (simpleminded) users having to set their monitor etc. by themselves?

I do not have a preferred language to work with; Java, C(++), C#, anything would do as long as it runs on Windows 7+.

Comment: What language / framework are you using?  There are certainly APIs available that can be used to detect the setup of multiple display, as well as placing graphics at a given location on any display.

Comment: Are these APIs able to activate monitors? And do they work with most, if not all, drivers?

Comment: There is a standard Windows API to work with all of this, which is independent of the driver, yes.  And yes, you could even use this to activate additional monitors that are not yet activated - but I would strongly encourage you to leave this to the preference and control of the user.

Comment: If you can maybe give me some name/source of documentation/reference/anything, I can mark you as the answer. Couldn't find much with the keywords I came up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are just a few examples of APIs related to multiple monitors / displays (pretty much, first relevant results of a Google search):

- http://vb.mvps.org/articles/vsm20090302.pdf
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/multiplemonitor.aspx
- http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/programming/

`EnumDisplayMonitors` will be a common point for most of these, the documentation of which is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610%28VS.85%29.aspx :

> The EnumDisplayMonitors function enumerates display monitors
>   (including invisible pseudo-monitors associated with the mirroring
>   drivers) that intersect a region formed by the intersection of a
>   specified clipping rectangle and the visible region of a device
>   context. EnumDisplayMonitors calls an application-defined
>   MonitorEnumProc callback function once for each monitor that is
>   enumerated. Note that GetSystemMetrics (SM_CMONITORS) counts only the
>   display monitors.

See also [`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413), which can be used to configure the displays, including "Position of the device in a multi-monitor configuration."